# Link hadoop installed with sdkman to brew

Tags: homebrew

I installed hadoop with sdkman and now I'm trying to install Hive with homebrew but brew wants to install hadoop again because it doesn't know hadoop is already installed on my computer.

I use --ignore-dependencies flag as workaround but it's not a best practice.

Do you know how can I link my hadoop installation done with sdkman to brew?

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to use a non-Homebrew `hadoop` with Homebrew `hive`, see https://docs.brew.sh/Building-Against-Non-Homebrew-Dependencies

> To improve quality and reduce variation, Homebrew now exclusively supports using the default formula, as an ordinary dependency, and no longer supports using arbitrary alternatives.

You will have to install Hive manually: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/gettingstarted#GettingStarted-InstallingHivefromaStableRelease

> #### Installing Hive from a Stable Release
>
> Start by downloading the most recent stable release of Hive from one of the Apache download mirrors (see [Hive Releases](https://hive.apache.org/downloads.html)).
>
> Next you need to unpack the tarball. This will result in the creation of a subdirectory named `hive-x.y.z` (where `x.y.z` is the release number):
>
> ```
> $ tar -xzvf hive-x.y.z.tar.gz
> ```
>
> Set the environment variable `HIVE_HOME` to point to the installation directory:
>
> ```
> $ cd hive-x.y.z
> $ export HIVE_HOME={{pwd}}
> ```
>
> Finally, add `$HIVE_HOME/bin` to your PATH:
>
> ```
> $ export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH
> ```